# how i can access to this values? php

Tags: php, salesforce

I want print: `Id`, `Nombre_del_paciente__c`, `Fecha_de_la_cita__c` and `Hora_de_la_cita__c`

This is `print_r($response);` result:

```
Object ( 
    [queryLocator] => [done] => 1 [records] => Array ( 
            [0] => SObject Object (
                [type] => 
                    Cita__c [fields] => stdClass Object 
                    ( 
                        [Nombre_del_paciente__c] => 0030O000021cPBuQAM 
                        [Fecha_de_la_cita__c] => 2017-11-28 
                        [Hora_de_la_cita__c] => 15:30 
                    ) 
                [Id] => a000O00000tmZH6QAM 
            )
    ) [size] => 1 
)
```

I do this and I can acces to ID value... but i cant acceso to other values:

```
<table>
                                <tr>
                                    <th>ID </th>
                                    <th>Nombre_del_paciente__c</th>
                                    <th>Fecha_de_la_cita__c</th>
                                    <th>Hora_de_la_cita__c</th>
                                </tr>
                                <?php
                                    foreach ($response->records as $record) {
                                        echo '<tr> 
                                                    <td>'.$record->Id.'</td>
                                                    <td></td>
                                                    <td></td>
                                                    <td></td>
                                            </tr>';
                                    }
                                ?>
                            </table>
```

Im try to do:

```
$record->type->Nombre_del_paciente__c
$record->Cita__c ->Nombre_del_paciente__c
$record->Cita__c['fields'] ->Nombre_del_paciente__c
```

but i cant acces to values

Comment: Try `$record->type->fields->Nombre_del_paciente__c`

Comment: Im try... but dont work

Answer (score 1):

Your key 'type' is not a object array. you can try this-

```
$record->type['fields']->Nombre_del_paciente__c
$record->type['fields']->Fecha_de_la_cita__c
$record->type['fields']->Hora_de_la_cita__c
```